# Combination with partial overlapping

Tags: probability

I have this problem: I have 18 questions and 4 possible answers for each. The four answers have four different weight: 1,4,9,99.

I want to find all the combination of possible answer for the 18 questions.

I think the model should be the product of these vectors without repetition (each vector is the set of possible answers for one oh the 18 questions):

[Combination of answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVyXL.png)

My question is: is there a mathematic method to calculate these combiantions?

Comment: What do the weights mean? Is that how scores are calculated?

Comment: @onceUponACriniod yes, they are